# is it necessary for the socket to immediately receive data/java

Tags: java, sockets

I am working on a network simulation in java. I send data from the server side to the client side. The client receives this data and then client starts to read data which has come into its own buffer and shows it on the client terminal that how much data has arrived further "whereas" on the server side, it keep sending data. Receiving statements are also written on the client side but the client is busy in reading in its buffer. After it finishes, it receives data from server. Sometimes, when I run the program, the data sent from the server is not read and exception occurs "Connection reset". Is it timing issue? Should the data sent from server be immediately received at client side? or due to some other reason?
Here is the server's side code:

```
soc.sendHP_Grant(grantSizeHP2);     //soc is the socket's object
soc.sendLP_Grant(grantSizeLP2);
soc.sendGrant_info(grantStartTime);
soc.sendGrant_info(grantEndTime);
```

whereas on the client side:

```
receivedGrant_HP = socOnu.receiveReportHP();
receivedGrant_LP = socOnu.receiveReportLP();
startTime = socOnu.receiveGrant_Info();             
endTime = socOnu.receiveGrant_Info();
onu2.accessTraffic("ONU2-Traffic-report-2.txt");
```

After that, I am again using the server's side code to send further data and then again I use client's side code to receive data. According to me, it's happening because I am not immediately receiving data at client side. Please mention the solution or if there is some other reason. Please mention with solution. Thanks in advance

This is the code which (is causing problem) I am using for receiving data at client side:

```
public double receiveReportHP() throws IOException{

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        double reportHP = dis.readDouble();     //exception on this line
        return reportHP;

    }
```

whereas the sending side code is (working fine):

```
public double receiveReportForHP() throws IOException{

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        double reportHP = dis.readDouble();
        return reportHP;

    }
```

Comment: Connection reset means the other side has suddenly disconnected in the middle of a transaction. Something is likely wrong with your server code that causes it to crash, or close the socket prematurely

Comment: @Natecat , I used the same code before and read the data for 8 clients (when I was not reading files in the code) and it worked perfect. Moreover, it is reading data but sometimes data of 6 clients is read and sometimes 7. 8 is never read

Comment: Are you sure the internet is reliable on both sides?

Comment: @Natecat , I didn't get what you have mentioned in class comment. Sorry I am a BS student (and learning). What is meant by internet is reliable on both sides??

Comment: Can you rely on the connection to the internet to stay active on both the server and the client?

Comment: @Natecat  No, internet connection is not required. It's just a desktop application working with sockets. I am using ports for my program.

Comment: You'll need to post the actual sending code, and the code that acquires the Sockets and streams at both ends and also show where you are closing things. Also, is the server reading everything the client sends?

Comment: @EJP , I have edited the question and mentioned the line of code which is causing problem for receiving data of 8th client. I don't know why it is not working for 8th client because the same function is receiving data for other 7 clients

Comment: You still haven't posted the actual sending code. NB you should use the same streams for the life of the socket, not new ones per item transmitted.

Comment: I suggest using BufferedInputStream esp as you are read small portions at a time. It won't fix your problem but will improve performance. I also suggest writing your code so `socket.getInputStream()` is only called once. Not every time you use it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey , Now the code is working fine. Thanks!